# PS to export 'ManagedBy' - need additional data. SamAccountName, attribute09

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that works to export the 'ManagedBy' field from a list of security groups.  It exports 2 columns - the security group name and the DistinguishedName of the user in the ManagedBy field.  I need to export more info on the user if possible.  I'd like to get the SamAccountName and extended attribure09 which is a employee ID.  Here is the code that is working.  Stuck on what to do here. Thanks!

```
$Groups = Get-Content C:\Scripts\Groups.txt
$Groups | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $_ -properties ManagedBy | Select Name,ManagedBy
} | Export-CSV Groups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From feedback in comments, if I understand correctly, you're looking to get the `extensionAttribute9` and `SamAccountName` from the `ManagedBy` value. In which case you can try the following:

```bash
Get-Content C:\Scripts\Groups.txt |
    Get-ADGroup -Properties ManagedBy |
    ForEach-Object {
        $managedBy = $_.ManagedBy |
            Get-ADObject -Properties extensionAttribute9, SamAccountName

        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name                = $_.Name
            ManagedBy           = $_.ManagedBy
            SamAccountName      = $managedBy.SamAccountName
            extensionAttribute9 = $managedBy.extensionAttribute9
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv Groups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note: There is no need to `ForEach-Object` to query the groups, `-Identity` can be bound from pipeline.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this may be more complex that I thought.  I tried your code but the SamAccountName is the name of the security group.  So it is not grabbing the SamAccountName of the user from the ManagedBy field.  The extended attribute is blank because that does not exist for security group
I suspect I need to run something like what I started with, than take the output of ManagedBy (DistinguishedName) then run another script to pull ManagedBy, SamAccountName, extensionAttribute9 for that user.

Comment: @j-mo ah so you're looking to gather that info from the ManagedBy, I get it. See my update